# Uploading multiple files with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http, post

I am currently trying to upload multiple files through an API endpoint. It's a POST request, its body contains form-data.

I am unable to get it through for each loop, though it works just fine if there's no foreach and there's only one file.

Code that doesn't work:

```
$path = config('app.photos_dir');

        if($request->hasFile('photos'))
        {
                if (!file_exists($path)) {
                    mkdir($path, 0777, true);
                }
                try {
                    $files = $request->file('photos');

                    foreach ($files as $file){
                        $file->move($path, $files->getClientOriginalName());
                    }
                    
                } catch (\Exception $exception) {

                    return response(['status' => '500', 'error' => 'Error while uploading files'], 500);
                }
                
                return response(['status' => '200', 'data' => ['Photos uploaded correctly']], 200);


        }
```

As outlined above, it starts working once I remove foreach clause(although this will only upload the first/last file selected in the 'upload' windows prompt)

```
$files = $request->file('photos');
                    $files->move($path, $files->getClientOriginalName());
```

Not really sure what is wrong here. I found other folks which had no problems in looping through the request files, but in my case, it won't go no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - I found the solution. For some reason, I had to append the body's parameter name from photos to photos[]

Comment: In such case, please just leave a comment above and feel free to remove the question.